# React on first click State not updated and delayed for localStorage

Tags: reactjs, onclick

```
      const [storageValue, setStorageValue] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productCardsId')) || []);

  const localStoreHandler = productId => {
    setStorageValue(prevValue => [productId, prevValue?.[0]]);
    localStorage.setItem('productCardsId', JSON.stringify(storageValue));
  };
```

When I set setStorageValue with a first value I only get an empty array. After the second click, I get the value but delayed. How I can update the state on the first click? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`setStorageValue` is an async action, so `localStorage.setItem('productCardsId', JSON.stringify(storageValue));` will receive the first stale value. There are two options: One is that you update `localStorage` inside your state update, or have a hook that detects changes in the value and updates `localStorage` accordingly.

Option 1

```js
setStorageValue(prevValue => {
  const nextValue = [productId, prevValue?.[0]]
  localStorage.setItem('productCardsId', JSON.stringify(nextValue));
  return nextValue
});
```

Option 2

```js
const localStoreHandler = productId => {
  setStorageValue(prevValue => [productId, prevValue?.[0]]);
};

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('productCardsId', JSON.stringify(storageValue));
}, [storageValue])
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  for the solutions. Both options work. I select the first option.